# How to type in another application?

Tags: python, python-3.8

I'm trying to create a speech-to-text keyboard. But I don't know how to type/send the text to other applications like Microsoft word, google search box, Facebook message line edit, etc. I know how to create a pyqt python application, all I need to know is how to type the text or interact with other applications. My code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Speak Anything :")
    audio = r.listen(source, 8)
try:
    text = r.recognize_google(audio, language="bn-BD")
    print("You said : {}".format(text))
except:
    print("Sorry could not recognize what you said")
```

Comment: Maybe something like [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) could make things easier? Not sure though, I haven't done anything like that before.

Comment: Your question is too broad and needs focus. Microsoft Word is a desktop application while Google search is a website. This changes the way to handle it

Comment: using modules `PyAutoGUI`, `pynput`, `keyboard` you can send keys to active window - if Microsoft Word will be active then it will send to Microsoft Word but if you accidetly change active window then it will send to other window. They can't send always to selected window. It may need modules which use Windows API. Maybe [PyWinAuto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)